# Transform Pandas Dataframe to RCV

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, pivot

I have a dataframe that represents a covariance matrix s.th. like this

```
names = ['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE']
x_ = np.random.normal(size=5)
y_ = np.random.normal(size=5)
z = np.vstack((x_, y_))
cov_mat = np.cov(z.T)
cov_mat = np.triu(cov_mat, k=0)
cov_mat_df = pd.DataFrame(cov_mat)
cov_mat_df.index = names
cov_mat_df.columns = names
```

which results in

```
          AA        BB        CC        DD        EE
AA  0.271191 -1.064020 -0.311409  0.834741 -0.464261
BB  0.000000  4.174687  1.221814 -3.275110  1.821531
CC  0.000000  0.000000  0.357591 -0.958533  0.533111
DD  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  2.569378 -1.429021
EE  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.794784
```

I would like to save this as a csv, whilst dropping all the 0s for memory size reasons in the following format

```
Idx1    Idx2    Value
  AA      AA    0.271191
  AA      BB    -1.064020
  AA      CC    -0.311409
  ...     ...   ....
  DD      EE    -1.429021
  EE      EE    0.794784
```

I tried using pandas pivoting functions but I think I need the reverse of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with replace `0` to `NaN`, so this rows are dropped:

```
df = df.replace(0,np.nan).stack().rename_axis(('idx1','idx2')).reset_index(name='Value')
print (df)
   idx1 idx2     Value
0    AA   AA  0.271191
1    AA   BB -1.064020
2    AA   CC -0.311409
3    AA   DD  0.834741
4    AA   EE -0.464261
5    BB   BB  4.174687
6    BB   CC  1.221814
7    BB   DD -3.275110
8    BB   EE  1.821531
9    CC   CC  0.357591
10   CC   DD -0.958533
11   CC   EE  0.533111
12   DD   DD  2.569378
13   DD   EE -1.429021
14   EE   EE  0.794784
```

Comment: perfect thanks, any idea how I can ignore the 0s as well, I use np.triu to only get the upper half of the matrix